# C#: How to get the type definition of my enum..?

Tags: c#, enums, types

This feels like a really basic question, but I can't figure it out anyway..

How do I get the type of System.Windows.Visibility? I need to pass the type definition to a function. More precisly I'm writing unit tests for a IValueConverter I'm writing where the target type is a System.Windows.Visibility. What do I pass as target type when calling Convert..?

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`typeof(System.Windows.Visibility)`

Comment: Woot?! Well, of course I tried typeof, but I got some odd errors I didn't understand, so I got misled.. The errors turns out not to address the typeof, so I just got confused at the end of a long day. Of course typeof is correct. Thanks! I said it felt basic ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Are you asking for [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(VS.71).aspx) ?

```
typeof(System.Windows.Visibility)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
typeof(System.Windows.Visibility);
```

will do the trick :)

lol, 3 exactly the same answers within a minute of each other :/